# Check if pause() exists in <video> (Safari 5.1.7 on Windows - HTML5 videos)

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

Safari 5.1.7 on Windows doesn't support `play()`, `pause()` etc. on `video` elements when Quicktime is not installed.

Therefore, I'd like to detect if it's supported or not.

```
jQuery('video').each(function(){
    this.pause();
});
```

This returns: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.pause()')`

```
jQuery('video').each(function(){
    if( <<I need a way to check if pause is in this>> ){
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

I'm looking for a way to do this properly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some feature detection:

```
if (this.pause) {
  this.pause();
}
```

You could even test if it is a function:

```
if (this.pause && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.pause) === '[object Function]') {
  this.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('video').each( function () {
    if (this.pause) {  //use it as a truthy check
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple and I was thinking about `typeof`, `instanceof`, `hasProperty`, `in` and many other methods...